# VBA TimeValue() and Spreadsheet Formula TimeValue()

Tags: vba, excel

Good morning all,

I have over 20,000 time inputs in a column such as `6/23/2015 1:05:37.7 PM` and need to transfer it in a time value Excel can manage.

I managed to find a workaround:

```
Set wrTB = Worksheets("TEST BENCH Data")
wrTB.UsedRange
lastRowTB = wrTB.UsedRange.Rows.Count
lastColumnTB = wrTB.UsedRange.Columns.Count

If lastRowTB > 1 Then 'makes sure there is data on the worksheet
    If wrTB.Cells(7, lastColumnTB) <> "" Then 'makes sure time has not already been formated
        Dim aTempsTB As Variant, TempsTB() As String
        ReDim TempsTB(lastRowTB - 7, 1)
        aTempsTB = wrTB.Range(wrTB.Cells(8, 2), wrTB.Cells(lastRowTB, 2))
        For i = 1 To lastRowTB - 7
            TempsTB(i - 1, 0) = Right(aTempsTB(i, 1), 13)
        Next i
        wrTB.Range(wrTB.Cells(8, lastColumnTB + 2), wrTB.Cells(lastRowTB, lastColumnTB + 2)).NumberFormat = "[h]:mm:ss.000"
        wrTB.Cells(8, lastColumnTB + 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=TIMEVALUE(RC[-1])"
        wrTB.Cells(8, lastColumnTB + 2).AutoFill Destination:=wrTB.Range(wrTB.Cells(8, lastColumnTB + 2), Cells(lastRowTB, lastColumnTB + 2)), Type:=xlFillDefault
        wrTB.Range(wrTB.Cells(8, lastColumnTB + 1), wrTB.Cells(lastRowTB, lastColumnTB + 1)) = TempsTB
        Columns(lastColumnTB + 2).Copy
        Columns(lastColumnTB + 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Columns(lastColumnTB + 1).Delete
        wrTB.UsedRange
        lastColumnTB = wrTB.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    End If
End If
```

Basically, it works, but it is some ugly workaround I'd like to change to something more "professional"

If I change the code to:

```
For i = 1 To lastRowTB - 7
    TempsTB(i - 1, 0) = TimeValue(Right(aTempsTB(i, 1), 13))
Next i
```

I get a Type Mismatch error, I also tried setting temporary variables to make sure the arrays weren't causing the trouble, but it still doesn't work...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With data in **B1**, this will convert it into a usable **time**

```
Sub OutOfTime()
    Dim s As String
    s = Range("B1").Text
    ary = Split(s, " ")
    Range("B1").Formula = "=timevalue(""" & ary(1) & " " & ary(2) & """)"
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like I don't have enough reputation to upvote your comment, but thanks, that works perfectly, i only need to fit it in an array and it'll be done!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the formula:

```
=TIMEVALUE(TEXT(A1,"hh:mm:ss"))
```

and keep the text you have there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your time is too specific for Excel. Excel recognizes only time down to the second. But you have afterwards milliseconds. This is what is causing the problem and why Excel does not recognize it. You need to rid yourself of the milliseconds in the source (the dot after the seconds and what follows before the PM).

Doesn't work:

```
Debug.Pring IsDate("6/23/2015 1:05:37.7 PM")
```

Works:

```
Debug.Pring IsDate("6/23/2015 1:05:37 PM")
```